# The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference

Tags: azure-synapse, data-ingestion

I am having trouble completing an excersice on the Microsoft Learn platform.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/examine-components-of-modern-data-warehouse/5-exercise-azure-synapse

I have followed the instructions, but get the following error

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FndWf.jpg)

[Source settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdDWj.jpg)

Does anyone know what's causing this, and how I can fix the issue?

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue too. Unless I missed a step in the Explore Azure Synapse Analytics exercise (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/examine-components-of-modern-data-warehouse/5-exercise-azure-synapse), I found the issue to be that the source linked service was not being created for some reason in Steps 3 and 4. *I suggest doing the following in a different tab, so you can come back to Ingest Data wizard later to pick up where you left off.* I created the source linked service by going to my workspace, then clicking on the "Manage" icon (the one with the wrench on the briefcase). After that, click on "Linked services" followed by clicking on "+ New". At this point, a number of connection icon should appear. In the search bar type "HTTP" and click on it and click "continue". This will bring up a form that will be the same as the one you saw in step 3 of the Explore Azure Synapse Analytics exercise. Fill it out as directed in the exercise, and you should have a source linked service connection of Type "HTTP" created.
[Screenshot of Buttons to Click on to Create Source Linked Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzNbq.png)

As long as you've completed the rest of the steps of the exercise, going back to the Deployment step and proceeding should now allow it successfully complete.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [**same document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/examine-components-of-modern-data-warehouse/5-exercise-azure-synapse). When I tried in my environment, I got the same error.

[image: Ref2]

**Solution :**

I was able to solve by [**Connecting with GitHub**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control#connect-with-github) and [**Troubleshooting Git integration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#troubleshooting-git-integration).

> **Note:** Disconnect from the ***existing git repo***. ***Reconnect*** back to the ***same repo***, and ***create a new git branch***. Then
> use git to create more ***commits*** on top of that ***branch***.

[image: Ref2]

**Sample dataset:**

[image: Ref1]

**Deployment status:**

[image: Ref6]

**Linked service:**

[image: Ref8]

For more in **detail**, please **refer** to the below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#connect-to-a-git-repository

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#best-practices-for-cicd

Comment: The Synapse tutorial does not require the existence of git repository. Products.csv access through HTTP does not require git repo. Or may be I am missing out on something.

Comment: Thanks you @Pallavi for the comment ,After previewing the data, on the Source/Configuration **step 6** try to change **Row delimiter** as **Default (\r,\n, or \r\n)** and also **Step 9**  Configuration substep ,please change Row delimiter as **Default (\r,\n, or \r\n)** .