# Data ingestion pipeline in Azure Synapse gives BadRequest ERROR

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I am relatively new to Azure Analytics area.

I am getting following error while ingesting data in Azure Synapse using pipeline mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/examine-components-of-modern-data-warehouse/5-exercise-azure-synapse) exercise.

However, at the end, when I try to deploy the data ingestion pipeline, it gives me following error.

```
BadRequest The document creation or update failed because of invalid reference 'adventureworks'
```

[image]

I tried removing the space between the connection name (which it had earlier). Tried changing the name, which I thought might be taking from somewhere else. But, still it gives ERROR. I can also access products.csv when tried accessing directly.

Is there any other way I can troubleshoot this problem?
Or is this documentation missing any important step or something changed after this doc and its not updated accordingly?

Comment: Please check this thread which provides a solution for similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72416798/the-document-creation-or-update-failed-because-of-invalid-reference

Answer (score 0):

- As per the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/examine-components-of-modern-data-warehouse/5-exercise-azure-synapse),
  try to change the **step 6 & 9** from Ingest data -> 6th point
  `Row delimiter` as Default `(\r,\n, or \r\n)` from the above.
- As we implemented and followed the same steps and here it is a working solution for the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72421204/18935775).
- And as per @ChiragMishra's reply [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2dda216-bf65-4f88-b50b-567c79e5c741/error-creating-linked-service-that-references-azure-key-vault-linked-service), maybe you have not published the linked service once you created, recheck it after `connection` modified (space removed) have you hit the `publish`.